# Angular.js - using NG-Grid, how to get the length of value inside cell. Nothing seems to work

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am new to Angular and NG-Grid and trying desperately at a new company to get up to speed on it.
Using NG-grid for Anugular.js is there a way to format a cell using custom cell template if a cell contains more than x number of characters. I've search the web and their API and examples but cannot find an answer to this one. For instance if a cell has more than 40 characters make the background of that cell red.  It doesn't seem to like the .length() function for  comparison some reason.

This works great:

```
{green: row.getProperty(col.field) > 30}>
```

But this doesn't

```
{green: row.getProperty(col.field).length() < 40}>
```

AM I using the .length function wrong here or can it even be used inside ng-grid cells?
How do you get the length of the value inside a cell?

Here is a basic PLNKR based on their simple example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/fCUpoZ81vxFgt9sBHznz

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `length` instead of `length()` function. Its a string property not a function.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8KB8Rje0wNc2OpyUwOYZ?p=preview

Comment: Hi Thank you very much.  I need more reputations to upvote this, but very much appreciated.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that once as well, but anyway I feel really quite stupid now.  Thanks again.